# Is it possible to get VsCode Intellisense to sense against source produced by the C preprocessor?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Say I have a C program that looks something like this...

```c
#define Pointlike(type) \
    type lat;\
    type lng;
    
typedef struct Point {
    Pointlike(void*)
} Point;

typedef struct {
    Pointlike(int)
} IntPoint;

int main(){

    Point *point = &(Point){.lat = (void*) 0, .lng = (void*) 1};
    IntPoint *intPoint = &(IntPoint){ .lat = 0, .lng = 1 };
    IntPoint *unsafe = (IntPoint*) point;

    return 0;
}
```

Under my current configuration, VsCode Intellisense does not recognize the fields that would be provided by `Pointlike`.

Is there something I'm missing in my config? I could imagine this is the intended behavior because I wouldn't necessarily expect Intellisense to run the preprocessor by default. Is there a way for example to pipe `gcc -E` into Intellisense to somehow pick up these symbols?

Comment: This really doesn't seem to have anything to do with C++. If it did I would have been all like *ewwwwwwwww* but since I didn't I don't think the C++ tag really applies.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Happy to remove. I only tagged it that way because all of the VsCode documentation presents Intellisense for C as C/C++ Intellisense.

Comment: Yes but if it was C++ a potential (and recommended) solution would be to remove the `#define` altogether and just do `template<class T> struct Point { ... };` instead which would likely avoid the problem you are experiencing. Instead however it's more centric to VSCode and how you're constructing your C code to accomplish something that is done differently in C++

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of C/C++ Intellisense, this appears to work out of the box.